# Language that is CFL by Odgen but not by pumping lemma

Tags: context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

I recently studied about [Odgen's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogden%27s_lemma) and the [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages).
I deduced that Ogden's lemma is a general form and was interested:
Is there a CFL language by Odgen's but not by the pumping lemma?

Comment: The answer is already in [Odgen's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogden%27s_lemma): "Ogden's lemma can be used to show that certain languages are not context-free in cases where the pumping lemma is not sufficient. An example is the language $\{a^ib^jc^kd^\ell \mid i = 0 \text{ or }j = k = l\}$".

Answer (score 0):

For example the language $L = \{a^q 0^n1^m2^p \mid q = 0 \text{ or } n=m=p \}$. We can mark all symbols but the $a$.